# Alarm Manager Not Working... android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext

Tags: android, alarmmanager

I want to invoke a method of an object from user defined class for a particular interval of time for say 2 hours. The input parameter is a Context object.

I have used AlarmReceiver Broadcast Receiver which I registered in manifest

```
<receiver android:name=".AlarmReceiver" android:process=":remote"></receiver>
```

I am trying to start alarm manager through a Broadcast Receiver when a particular activity occurs. For receiving the alarm broadcasts I have created alarmReceiver. Do I need any kind of intent-filter for receiving alarm intents???

My problem is I want the application context inside alarmreceiver, I tried using the context of onReceive method of AlarmReceiver but it throws

```
    android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext
```

error.

Any solution for this error? If needed I will publish my full code...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I use this code to activate periodic alarms via  broadcast receiver:

```
public class UpdateReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    public static final String LOG_TAG = "camerawatch.alarmactivator";
    public static final String ACTION = "de.pribluda.android.camerawatch.UPDATE_ALARM";

    public static void activate(Context context) {
        AlarmManager alarmService = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
        Intent intent = new Intent(ACTION);
        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_NO_CREATE);
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "pending intent: " + pendingIntent);
        // if no intent there, schedule it ASAP
        if (pendingIntent == null) {
            pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, 0);
            // schedule new alarm in 15 minutes
            alarmService.setInexactRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC, System.currentTimeMillis(),300000, pendingIntent);
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "scheduled intent: " + pendingIntent);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d(LOG_TAG, "received intent: " + intent);
        CameraWidgetProvider.displayCurrentState(context);
    }
}
```

Note, that activation is done in static method, so I can call it from almost everywhere. 
I schedule alarm if and only there is no such pending intent.   As for context - it is available virtually everywhere - In activity ( it is context itself ) in broadcast receiver (serice method parameter)  etc.

PS: broadcast receiver is preferable to service, because it does not run all the time.  When service  method returns, it is stopped and application is potentially disposed ( unles it does something else,  but mostly it stays around  in background). This provides better battery life

Comment: it works... thanks.... On addition is I added name to the intent and I am filtering the intent with the name... so no need to specify the alarm receiver in intent. Thanks :D

Answer (score 1):

You can try this link:
1) [AlarmManager and BroadcastReceiver instead of Service - is that bad ? (Timeout)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3117350/alarmmanager-and-broadcastreceiver-instead-of-service-is-that-bad-timeout-p)

2) [Android AlarmManager and BroadcastReceiver running in background Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7212109/android-alarmmanager-and-broadcastreceiver-running-in-background-service)

3) [android: running a background task using AlarmManager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3859489/android-running-a-background-task-using-alarmmanager)

also You can use Service for alarm:
For that you can use this link: http://android-er.blogspot.com/2010/10/simple-example-of-alarm-service-using.html

Answer (score 1):

You need something like this:

```
 public RepeatAlarm(Context context, Bundle extras, int timeoutInSeconds){
     AlarmManager alarmMgr = (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
     Intent intent = new Intent(context, RepeatAlarm.class);
     intent.putExtra(REMINDER_BUNDLE, extras);
     PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, intent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
     Calendar time = Calendar.getInstance();
     time.setTimeInMillis(System.currentTimeMillis());
     time.add(Calendar.SECOND, timeoutInSeconds);
     alarmMgr.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, time.getTimeInMillis(),timeoutInSeconds*1000, pendingIntent);
 }
```

I pass the application context to it.

Btw in your main class you could declare a static context and then use it in any other class of your project whenver you want the applications context.